# C: Scanning multiple chars and outputting all in a single line

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that scans multiple chars each time the program loops and then prints all the scanned characters at the end. However, the program only prints the first character scanned each in each loop. Does anyone have any suggestions as how to fix this? Also, I'm just a beginner.

```css
#include <stdio.h>

void f1();
void f2();
int i;
char letters[20];

int main()
{
 f1();
 printf("%s", letters);
}

void f1()
{
 for(i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
  f2();
 }
}

void f2()
{
 printf("Enter any 2 letters: ");
 scanf("%s", &letters[i]);
}
```

Comment: is your code compiling?

Comment: The number of global side effects going function to function in this code hurts my head.

Comment: yeah the code compiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in each loop you scan just a single character so when you print the array each character which is the first character of the input is printed out.

```
scanf("%s", &letters[i]);
```

You need to use a 2D array like

```
char letters[5][20];
```

To scan 5 strings of 20 characters each,the whole code would look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1();
void f2();
int i;
char letters[5][20];

int main()
{
    f1();
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
    printf("%s\n", letters[k]);
    return 0;
}

void f1()
{
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        f2();
    }
}

void f2()
{
    printf("Enter any 2 letters: ");
    scanf("%s", &letters[i]);
}
```

Comment: @grammer Yes when you want n strings of m characters each have a 2D array `n *m`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will take only two characters as input at a time:

Replace

```
void f2()
{
    printf("Enter any 2 letters: ");
    scanf("%s", &letters[i]);
}
```

With

```
void f2()
    {
        printf("Enter any 2 letters: ");
        scanf("%s", &letters[2*i]);
    }
```